# I get this error and don't know what to do with it

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

This is a small one page site and it worked great before I decided to put it on a heroku. During the deployment process, there were problems and solving them I came to this error. I do not know what this error is connected with, but I have already spent a lot of time solving it.

**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 138, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 65, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\Programming\Projects\chuchman\chuchman\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 8, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 58, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\storage.py", line 129, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 373, in __init__
    self.hashed_files = self.load_manifest()
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 383, in load_manifest
    content = self.read_manifest()
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 377, in read_manifest
    with self.open(self.manifest_name) as manifest:
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 36, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 231, in _open
    return File(open(self.path(name), mode))
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 37, in path
    if not self.location:
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 214, in location
    return os.path.abspath(self.base_location)
  File "E:\Programming\python\lib\ntpath.py", line 531, in abspath
    return normpath(_getfullpathname(path))
TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not function
```

**settings.py:**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'a93ccl2aptoz-8mo&obfz$69sdh)cdaxqca*9plaw#lt-i+bgs'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mpage.apps.MpageConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage',
]

WHITENOISE_USE_FINDERS = True

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chuchman.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chuchman.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# print(BASE_DIR)
# PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# print(PROJECT_ROOT)






# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)



TEMPLATES_URL = '/templates/'

TEMPLATESFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from mpage import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.page_ru),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def index():
    STATISTIC = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.130'}
    page = requests.get(STATISTIC, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    convert = soup.findAll('tbody')
    convert = convert[0]
    convert = soup.findAll('tr')


    info = {}

    name = None
    g = 8
    while g != 228:
        line = convert[g]
        stat = line.findAll('td')
        if g == 107:
            name = 'Reunion'
        elif g == 188:
            name = 'Curacao'
        else:
            name = str(stat[1].text)
        if name == 'Ukraine':
            for i in range(2, 13):
                if i == 1 or i == 7 or i == 9 or i == 10 or i == 11:
                    continue

                temp = stat[i].text
                temp = temp.replace(' ', '')
                temp = temp.replace('N/A', '')
                temp = temp.replace(',', '')
                temp = temp.replace('+', '')
                if g == 8 and i == 11:
                    temp = stat[i].text
                    pp = temp.find('.')
                    temp = temp[0: pp]

                try:
                    temp = int(temp)
                except Exception:
                    pass


                if i == 2:
                    stat_2 = temp
                elif i == 3:
                    stat_3 = temp
                elif i == 4:
                    stat_4 = temp
                elif i == 5:
                    stat_5 = temp
                elif i == 6:
                    stat_6 = temp
                elif i == 8:
                    stat_8 = temp
                elif i == 12:
                    stat_12 = temp
        g += 1

    info = {
        'country': 'Ukraine',
        'total_cases': stat_2,
        'new_cases': stat_3,
        'total_deaths': stat_4,
        'new_deaths': stat_5,
        'total_recovered': stat_6,
        'active_cases': stat_8,
        'total_tests': stat_12, }


    return info
    

def page_ru(request):
    info = index()
    
    return render(request, 'mpage/index.html', context=info)


def page_ua(request):
    info = index()
    return render(request, 'mpage/index-ua.html', context=info)

def page_en(request):
    info = index()
    return render(request, 'mpage/index-en.html', context=info)
    
    return render(request, 'mpage/index.html', context=info)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'chuchman.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Hi, can you look to the value of path with the debugger ? It could help to understand the error.

Comment: Looks like it could point to your `page_ru` function in views.py as @LCMa mentioned you will need to find the value of path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your settings your `MIDDLEWARE` settings are as follows:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage',
]
```

Firstly `'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'` is a Storage backend and you have already set the `STATICFILES_STORAGE` setting to it. You should not add it to the middlewares.

Secondly `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'` is at the second last position even though the [documentation](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#enable-whitenoise) for WhiteNoise states:

> Edit your `settings.py` file and add WhiteNoise to the `MIDDLEWARE`
> list. The WhiteNoise middleware should be placed directly after the
> Django SecurityMiddleware (if you are using it) and before all other
> middleware

Therefore you need to change the `MIDDLEWARE` setting to:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # add here
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # Remove from here
    'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage', # Remove this
]
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `settings.py`
change

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'), # add str()
    }
}
```